# Can i start exercising two months before my marriage?

Tags: exercise

Can I start exercising two months before my marriage?
Some of them telling, stop exercising before two months of your marriage.
What can I do?

Comment: Why would you stop/not start exercising before your marriage? What are your concerns exactly?

Comment: No just now i started exercising to reduce my weight and make my body fix. But most peoples are telling not to continue, yet only 40 days more for marriage. And telling i will get muscle aches after marriage :)

Comment: I'd say there's nothing wrong with exercise, no matter if you marry or not. That's not a reason to stop exercising. What are those people's reasons for telling you to simply stop? Are they afraid you'll stress yourself out? Are they afraid you'll be so sore you can't stand in front of the altar (or whatever your ceremony of choice requires)? Or is it a traditional thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much you're planning on losing and the intensity of the exercises, you might not achieve your goal before your wedding day; however, that shouldn't stop you from exercising. 
 
Some people use exercises as a stress reliever; when they run, lift weights, do yoga, etc, the whole world *(including their stress)* disappears from their minds. They obtain relief using these activities. Others basically take walks to clear their minds. So, exercising can help you in these areas. 
 
You can start exercising almost anytime **as long as you aren't having unrealistic expectations *(such as losing 20 lbs in 40 days)***. Just start small and improve on it. 
 
More importantly, try to have fun with it; you'll lose weight easier this way :). 
 
*Now, go burn some goo :).*

Comment: @DineshBabu You're very welcome. We're all in this never-ending race to keep fit. We might as well have fun doing it :).

Comment: Thats cool. Thanks for all you guys, for your good suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And, of course, if exercise is causing the stress, feel free to cut it out. Weddings are stressful enough without feeling like you're failing by not getting your 100 pushups in every night.

Comment: @SeanDuggan That's very true. If exercises will stress you out, don't do it. Hopefully, if done right, it shouldn't add to your stress.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to stop exercising/not starting exercising before your marriage. Infact, many people start around this time to make sure they are looking their best for the big day!

I exercised right up to my wedding day, including a run on the actual day!

If you are worried about muscle aches, stop a couple of days before.

The only other thing to keep an eye on, if you are fairly inactive now, is that you may lose weight before your wedding.  Just make sure that the wedding outfit still fits.

Comment: Actually, there are several reasons to stop: No time, too much stress, risk of injury, maybe even cultural considerations. That's why I feel answering this question is premature, given the almost non-existent context of the question.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla depending on the exercises being done, this is actually a good reason to exercise. Many people reduce stress by working out. For those 30 mins to 1 hour, you forget your whole life and focus on the exercise.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla exercise may be a stress reliever.  But I agree with your assertion regarding the lack of context.

Comment: I _knew_ people would point that out, as soon as I wrote it :p. Under the wrong circumstances, it can also _add_ stress though. I guess that was my point.

Comment: @Tracy you ran on your wedding day? You weren't trying to run away from it, were you? :)

Comment: @kneel-Before-ZOD - still married, and still running, so it didn't do me any harm!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you may want to take up with your tailor.

If you have been cutting, try to go to a maintenance workout/diet a few weeks before your final measurements.

The main point is that you don't want your wedding suit/dress to be anything other than a perfect fit. With most tailor arrangements this will mean you will need to maintain stable measurements during a number of weeks prior to your wedding.